# how do I compare first object of date time to another object of date time in php

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

here I am using one date time object is this

```
 $cdate  = date('d/m/Y h:i:sa')
```

and another date time object is this

```
$udate = date("d/m/Y h:i:sa", strtotime("72 hours"));
```

for comparing I am using this condition

```
 if($cdate >= $udate)
```

but problem is this...in this case its only comparing only day not entire date and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings returned from `date()` are only comparable in certain circumstances. You should use `DateTime()` whose objects are always comparable:

```
$cdate  = new DateTime();
$udate = new DateTime('+3 days');
if($cdate >= $udate) {

}
```

Comment: Can we just make this the canonical sticky answer and be done with date comparison questions in PHP ;)

Comment: but I am unable to insert $udate in database. I am to fetch this update date from database and then compare as you suggested above

Comment: You just need to format it into a string when you are done with your comparison: `echo $udate->format('Y-m-d H;I;s');`

Comment: how to I make again same object of type DateTime after fetching update date from database. i am doing this –

Comment: $select = "select * from user where mac_address='$getMac'"; $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select); $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); $updated_date =$row['updated_date']; $d2 = new DateTime($updated_date); $ud1 = $d2->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa'); if($cdate >= $d2){ echo 'i am here'; }

Comment: Why don't you ask axiac as they gave you the answer you selected as the best answer?

Comment: @anilkrvijay Is my delay on answering your question the reason you changed the accepted answer? Why don't you just try until you find the best solution yourself? This is how you learn, not by waiting for others to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtotime($cdate) >= strtotime($udate)){
// your condition
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: in this case i am unable to find the value of strtotime($cdate). when i am testing it on server, its giving the value of strtotime($cdate) none

Answer (score 0):

The `date()` function returns a string - not a DateTime object. As such, the `>=` comparison you are doing is a **string** comparison, not a comparison of the dates/times.

If you really want to do string comparison, use a format where such sorting will make sense, such as ISO 8601. You can do this trivially with the format 'c'.

Much better, however, would be to compare actual DateTime objects or the integer timstamps (such as what you would get from `time()`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code wrong for comparing dates, because date returns string.

Try this:

```
$cdate = new DateTime();
$udate = new DateTime('72 hours');

if($udate > $cdate) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't compare date times and there are no objects (like in [`OOP`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)) in your code. `$cdate` and `$udate` are [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), that's why they are compared using the strings comparison rules (i.e. the dictionary order).

You can either use timestamps (that are just integer numbers of seconds):

```
// Use timestamps for comparison and storage
$ctime = time();
$utime = strtotime("72 hours");
// Format them to strings for display
$cdate = date('d/m/Y h:i:sa', $ctime);
$udate = date('d/m/Y h:i:sa', $utime);
// Compare timestamps
if ($ctime < $utime) {
    // Display strings
    echo("Date '$cdate' is before date '$udate'.\n");
}
```

Or you can use objects of type `DateTime`:

```
$cdate = new DateTime('now');
$udate = new DateTime('72 hours');

// You can compare them directly
if ($cdate < $udate) {
    // And you can ask them to format nicely for display
    echo("Date '".$cdate->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa')."' is before date '".
         $udate->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa')."'\n");
}
```

Comment: I am inserting $cdate and $udate in database then fetching updated_date from database. after that I am comparing as you suggested me but In the case of object of type DateTime...I am unable to insert $udate in database

Comment: You don't insert `DateTime` objects into the database. But you can use their [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to produce strings ready to be inserted in the database (with `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` or to be displayed (using whatever format suits better your application and language conventions about formatting the dates).

Comment: how to I make again same object of type DateTime after fetching update date from database. i am doing this

Comment: $select = "select * from user where mac_address='$getMac'";
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
                  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                       
                         $updated_date =$row['updated_date'];                                                                      $d2 =  new DateTime($updated_date);
                       
                       $ud1 = $d2->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa');                                 if($cdate >= $d2){ echo 'i am here'; }

Comment: The code is correct. If the type of column `update_date` is `DATE` or `DATETIME` then your code works well. Otherwise, change the column type in the database. Always store dates and times using the correct column types in the database, not as strings. And remember to not compare the string representations but either timestamps (see function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)) or [`DateTime` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).